# Good resourses to learn PCB designing

Tags: pcb

I am a beginner at PCB designing. I believe a good way to learn to design PCBs is to design them myself and then check how I did. I wanted to know of any resourses where people post their PCB designs and respective circuit diagrams online? So that I can refer to these designs?

Comment: Google is the best resource, as there are more of these sources than could reasonably be listed, although some people around here might have favorites.

Comment: Read a bunch of books on pcb design,  read some tutorials, most of all,  build your own and learn from your mistakes

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PrintedCircuitBoard/ is a community of people who exchange designs, provide feedback to one another and offer great advice!

Comment: about once a week, someone asks serious PCB layout-challenge questions on stackexchange: thermal management, ground-trash, crosstalk, etc. The discussions/comments are very useful mechanically, electrically, and thermally.

Comment: Here is a discussion about the need for planes (sometimes) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/415999/does-a-vcc-layer-cause-noise-to-a-4-layer-rf-pcb/416147#416147

Answer (score 1):

The key to learning **[anything](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/keyword-research)** is knowing the best keywords in an iterative process.

[In your case ; PCB DFM  IPC Standards](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pcb+design+dfm+ipc+standards&ia=web)

Then for [visual learners or ESL learners use images.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pcb%20design%20dfm%20ipc%20standards&iax=images&ia=images)

If you do not learn the Design Rules for Manufacturing and IPC standards for layout, thermal pads, gap, materials, stackup designs etc, looking at online sites may be bad examples with poor practices by those who want help.   I would not recommend any one site shared by newbies.